# THREE JS Cross origin Collada file

Tags: cors, cross-domain

When trying to load Collada file from my server I get the Cross Origin error so my file is inaccessible

Link: https://codepen.io/RedKizaru/pen/MBXYbV

```js
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "https://hydle.000webhostapp.com/host/obj/stand.dae";
script.integrity = "sha384-tSi+YsgNwyohDGfW/VhY51IK3RKAPYDcj1sNXJ16oRAyDP++K0NCzSCUW78EMFmf";
script.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

How can I get rid of the cross origin block ??

Comment: This is not a ThreeJS question. This is an issue with CORS. You need to set up your server to allow sharing assets with `https://codepen.io` if that's where you want your assets to be available. How do you set up your server to allow CORS? Well, that depends on what type of server you're running. Is it running php, Node, other? You should also read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present/27280939#27280939

Comment: @Marquizzo Could not find a clear solution to use with Javascript. For the type of server I just put the files there for being used on other websites

Comment: That's because your server does not allow resource sharing with other websites. You have to modify your server settings to allow resource sharing. It probably won't be a JavaScript solution.

Comment: @Marquizzo I guess it's like you said, but honestly I don't Know how to do so .. any ideas how can that be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem:

Many Apache servers (like yours) have disabled resource-sharing with other servers by default. In your case, `https://hydle.000webhostapp.com` is not allowed to share the .dae file with `https://codepen.io`, which is why you're getting this error.

---

## Solution 1:

If you host your code and your .dae file on the same server, you won't run into any CORS issues, since they both have the same origin.

---

## Solution 2:

You'll need to upload a PHP script to your server that allows resource-sharing to specific domains. I won't write the whole code for you, but it goes something like this:

script.php:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://codepen.io");
    echo readfile("/path/to/file.dae");
?>
```

then you upload script.php to your server, and you'll be able to load that resource from codepen.io via JavaScript:

```
script.src = "https://hydle.000webhostapp.com/host/obj/script.php";
```

Accessing `script.php` this way will return the contents of `file.dae`. I don't recommend solution 2 because of security issues, but it's what you asked for. For more info on PHP's readfile, you can read [its documentation](http://php.net/readfile).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to append your collada file as a script, try this:

```
var url = "https://hydle.000webhostapp.com/host/obj/stand.dae";
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.setCrossOrigin("anonymous");
loader.load(url, function (collada) {
    scene.add(collada.scene);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that didn't do any change

Comment: @Devastarius are you running a webserver? Three.js needs a webserver to run.